# How to convert from BSTR to DATE

Tags: c++, windows, com, atlcom

```
COleVariant var(bstrString);    
var.ChangeType(VT_DATE);    
DATE date = var.date;
```

not seems to be working. Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: MacGyver! Buddy! How u doin' !

Answer (score 1):

What is happening?

Maybe [VarDateFromStr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221395.aspx) function works for you.

Best